# Speed up Meteor test refresh

Tags: node.js, testing, meteor, mocha.js

When testing a Meteor app, I notice that Meteor does a lot of repeated tasks, such as

- **Downloading missing packages (several seconds)**

  It seems that it would be more efficient to check for updated `package.json` and `.meteor/versions` before "downloading missing packages", especially when the only changes are within unit tests or other application-specific code (i.e. no new imports).
- **Building web.cordova (which I do not use)**

  I am pretty sure that specifying the target for testing is possible, so the project is only build for `web.browser`, for example.
- **If there are errors, everything is built and executed three times (and failing three times).**

  When  a test fail, why does it have to try again with the exact same code? Is there any use case where this makes sense?

Right now, every time a test module changes, it's several seconds before the tests are ran again because of all these tasks. Is there any way to optimize this and make it more efficient and faster?